# Parallelizing search in a 2D array on CUDA

Tags: search, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I have a 500 x 500 2D array of floats. I wish to search in the vertical and horizontal directions from the middle of the array for the first zero element in both directions. The output should be 4 indices for the first zero element in the North, South, East and West directions. Is there a way to parallelize this search operation on CUDA.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your data located on the GPU? If so, in what kind of memory space?

Comment: Also, please let us now if you are actually ignoring all array elements that are not directly in the N,S,W,E directions - or whether you want to search the "North quadrant", "East quadrant" etc.

Comment: Yes the array is stored in GPU memory and I  need to ignore all data that is not directly in the N, S, W and E directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes that you are not searching entire quadrants, but only the straight lines in each direction)

### 1. In case the array is in CPU memory

In fact, you have a search space of just 1,000 elements. The overhead of copying the data,  launching the kernel and waiting for the result is such that it is not worth your trouble.

Do it on the CPU. One of your axes already has the data nicely laid out, consecutively; probably best to work on that axis first. The other axis will be a bitch in terms of memory access, but that's life. You could go multi-threaded here, but I'm not sure it's worth your trouble for so little work. If you did, each thread would wait on its own element.

As far as the algorithm - since your data isn't sorted, it's basically a linear search (up to vectorization). If you've gone multi-threaded - perhaps use a shared variable which a thread occasionally polls to see if an "closer-to-the-center" thread has found a zero yet; and when a thread finds a zero, it updates that variable to let other threads know to stop working.

### 2. In case the array is in GPU global memory

Now you get lots of (CUDA) 'threads'. So, it makes less sense to use an atomic variable, or polling etc.

We treat each of the four directions separately (although it doesn't have to be 4 separate kernels).

As @RobertCrovella notes, you can treat this problem as a parallel reduction, with each thread assigned an input element: Initially, each thread holds a value of infinity (if its corresponding element is non-zero), or its distance from the center if its corresponding array value is 0. Now, the reduction operator is "minimum".

This is not entirely optimal, because when warp or block results are collected (as part of a parallel reduction), this problem allows for short-circuiting when the lowest non-infinity value is located. You can read up how parallel reduction is implemented - but I really wouldn't bother, because you have a very small amount of computational work here.

---

Note: It is also possible that your array is in GPU *array* memory. In that case you would get better locality in both dimensions

Comment: Thank you for your response. Given that the array is already in GPU memory, do you still think doing it in a parallel fashion (i.e. a parallel reduction as @Robert Crovella suggested) will not offer any significant performance gains. For me the problem is that I will have to maintain a copy of this array in the CPU memory as well, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear how you define "first zero element in the North, South, East and West directions" but I could imagine a rectangular data set broken into 4 quadrants along the diagonals.

We could label the top region the "north region" and we could label the other regions similarly.

with that assumption, In the worst case you have to check every element of the array.

Therefore one possible approach is a parallel reduction.

You would then do a parallel reduction on each region, such that the distance from the center (using the standard distance formula) is minimized, considering the zero elements in the region.

If you are actually only interested in the elements associated with the vertical axis and horizontal axis that pass through the center of the image, then another approach may be better.

Even in that case, I think a parallel reduction would be a typical approach, two for each axis, considering only the zero elements on the axis half.

Comment: I think OP meant they only search the straight line in each direction.

Comment: Clearly you think that way, based on your posted answer.  I found some uncertainty and chose to answer differently.  I've already acknowledged the possibililty of my error, in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To clarify I meant that I only need to search the straight line in each direction as @einpoklum mentioned.

Comment: I've covered my suggestion for that case as well in my answer (at least, with respect for a suggestion how to do it using parallel algorithms on data in device memory).